# configuring Hortonworks Data Platform Sandbox 2.6.5 from the command line

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hortonworks-sandbox

I am building a a demo/training environment for one of our products which work with Hive & Spark.  I am using HDP 2.6.5 and If I configure the hive settings I need (primarily these: [ACID Settings](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_data-access/content/ch02s05s01.html)) through the Ambari GUI it works fine.  But I want to automate this and setting these in hive-site.xml is not working (I have found many copies of this file, so it could simply be I am using the wrong one? )

How can I change from the command line what changes when I make changes in Dashboard->Hive->Configs ?
Where are these changes stored?  I am sure I have missed something obvious in the docs, but I can't find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads-up. HDP 2 will be end of life this year. It is probably not the best choice to build your product on. Consider looking into CDP, the successor of HDP which uses cloudera manager rather than Ambari. (Disclosure: Both platforms are built by my company).

Comment: We aren't building the product on it we support many hadoop distributions.  But we need a 'small; environment to demo out product with. CDP seems to no longer be available as a quickstart VM for recent versions.

Comment: Tons of companies still on HDP2... they will never upgrade to HDP3, and never upgrade to CD(x)....

Answer (score 1):

@Leigh K You should check out the Ambari REST API to make changes to hive.  I did not find a quick link to official documentation, but I was able to find this post that goes into detail using PIG:

https://markobigdata.com/2018/07/22/adding-service-to-hdp-using-rest-api/2/